# Picturebox with transparent background on top of WebBrowser

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, picturebox

I'm trying to make a Floating Player for videos, but I came across this problem that the background does not stay transparent on top of the Web Browser, how to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This looks like WinForms, right? Transparency is kind of a trick. The *transparent* background, here, is the PictureBoxes' parent background painted over the children's surface.  You'll have to refresh those control, keeping in mind that the WebBrowser really likes to be on top of the other controls. Or use an overlay, if you want to keep other controls on top of it.

Comment: I've already tested update controls using ".Update" and ".Refresh" on the buttons, but it didn't work!

Comment: Please, how to do it?!